# Sails.js , calling route from Controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

js. I want to know if there is any way to **call a route from a controller**.

I use **`res.view('/path/to/ejs',{"msg":"something"});`** to redirect to a .ejs file specifying the directory structure.

> Instead in some cases I would like use something like

**`res.route('/url',
{
  "msg":"something"
})`**

All I want to know is whether it is possible to achieve the same?

If YES then how?

Comment: res.redirect() will do the work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`res.view()`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/response-res/res-view) is **not** a redirect. Instead it renders the specified view. use [`res.redirect()`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/response-res/res-redirect) to send a 302 redirect. It makes no sense to pass locales to a redirect method since all modern browsers ignores response body on a redirect. Therefore res.redirect only accepts a url or path as parameter.

Comment: Thank you @jelhan for clarifying the matter. [upvoted]